# Unbalanced Panel Data Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, modeling, panel-data

Are there any methods in R that can handle unbalanced panel data for classification tasks? See the data below. I am trying to predict likelihood of failure (column C) using all the other data available. Suppose I have different groups of units (column B) each with different intervals for time (Column A). I'd like to use a mixed effect logistic regression model, but because the intervals and frequencies are different each group, the data is highly unbalanced. I've considered creating new features to extract the important elements of the date column (e.g. day of week, weekday/weekend, number of times group has appeared in time series, etc.), but I do not want to potentially lose the longitudinal aspect of the data.

Is there a machine learning algorithm that would be better suited for this task?

[image: sample data]

edit: in the real dataset, there is only one failure per group, but most times, no failures per group. Also, if there is a failure, it will happen on the last date listed for that group.

Comment: logistic regression is a probabilistic classifier and therefore can handle unbalanced data.  Why do you want to use mixed effects, which is for inference not prediction.  Just use regularised logistic regression

Comment: How would one handle the different time intervals/frequencies across the groups?  I am only familiar with logistic regression without any time component.

Comment: Perhaps a hazard model would be more appropriate?

Comment: A discrete time survival model could be used, where you predict eg probability of failure in each month, given no failure so far. This can be done by logistic regression.(basically expanding your data into a monthly timeseries for each component until failure. ( And adding all variables you see fit, eg total time)